# Changing precision on the decimal field causes SSIS Package to fail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a field in a Source table with data type decimal (10,2). 
The source field is being used in a simple Data Pump in one of the SSIS packages to insert data into another table to a field with exact datatype. 
Recently, the precision was changed to 18 in both source and destination tables, making the data type Decimal(18, 2).

The package started to fail on the server with a following error:

> Description: There was an error with output column "RunningTotal" (20) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (11). The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type."

When I went into the Advanced Editor of the OLE DB Source in the DataPump, I found that Output Column is still showing an old precision of 10.

Does this mean, that whenever such change occurs like changing the precision and not the entire datatype, a package needs to be manually updated and pushed to the server?
Or is there a way for the package to automatically recognize these types of changes?

Thank you very much for everyone's help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to update the metadata manually every time it changes in the source. The only way to avoid manual refresh is to explicitly define the metadata do use, which means a lot of `convert` in your queries.

For instance, change:

```
select id
  from mytable
```

into :

```
select convert(int, id) as id
  from mytable
```

So, when the datatype changes from int to bigint, you don't need to update the metadata. Beware, it can start failing because the bigint value is larger than the int size in SSIS tho!